# rails 5 redirect_back not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i have a admin edit page and `form` in here. when i submit the form, it is going to the `update` action and updates the admin, there is no problem. After the update, i want redirect to the index page in the same controller. But it gets redirected to the edit form again. I tried a couple of things but in vain and gets redirected to `edit` page. i tried too much things but it is always going to edit page.

**Controller** `(admins_controller.rb)`

```
class Admin::AdminsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @admins = Admin.all
  end

  def edit
    @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
    if @admin.update(admin_params)
      redirect_back fallback_location: admin_admins_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def admin_params
      params.require(:admin).permit(:id, :username, :password)
  end
end
```

I'm trying `admin_admins_path` it does not work.

Comment: is it `admin_admins_path` ? i think you have a typo there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`redirect_back` like its name, it redirects to the route which it submitted the request, in this case is the edit page.

you should use `redirect_to`

```
redirect_to admin_index_path
```